# Can't get the stdin stream of the executed process by node.js

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, electron, stdin, child-process

I'm trying to develop my extension for VSC (Visual Studio Code).

We have some application here that have command line input when launched and we can write in there some commands like in any terminal and get various results. This program supports inhouse programming language and with that we can modify it in the way we need. But with standard installation we have Emacs as developing tools so we want to write extension to VSC. And here is a first problem!

I'm trying to spawn or execFile via node's child_process and I can't get working stdin stream. After program starts and loaded it try to get stdin and faild with some kind of error: **"ASCII "readFromConsole: redirected terminal i/o failed last error 109"**.

But if we start this program from cmd it works fine and we can write commands into cmd.

I tried when "spawn" use 'pipe' method or 'IPC'. With 'IPC' method process doesn't close but not receiving any data with subprocess.send(). Pipe method or 'ignore' crashes the app after it's loaded.

I hope I can get some code example from you, guys, that helps me understand how properly work with stdin stream. It seems to me, that node.js process just closing its stream after it execute the program. So maybe some code example how to read from console, wait for input and keep stdin alive until my app or extension close itself.

With best regards,
Greg.

Comment: And yes! i've read all the StackOverflow about the child_process and the whole internet and google and didn't found the answer that suits me. So you're, guys, my last hope. :)

Comment: Another thought on my mind is that I need to write C++ Addon fro Node.js that will be transport between node and my child process... If that is the only way to do things done it will be the answer... But I hope that there is the another way to do so but C++ Addon.